# How to use duplicate named slots in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am working on a wrapped component for the v-stepper in Vuetify.  In this case, i want the user to define a slot when using the component and then i will use that slot name to build out the steps.

I need to have this slot exist for both a desktop view and a mobile view.  I tried using v-if to hide if mobile or not, but that caused other issues, so I went with v-show, but that gives me an error in developer console:

> Duplicate presence of slot "page6" found in the same render tree -
>   this will likely cause render errors.

**Here is how the component is structured** Note that these are in the same [.vue file](https://github.com/jasonwilczak/vuetify-simple-wizard/blob/master/src/components/SimpleWizard.vue)

Desktop snippet

```
<v-stepper-items>
    <v-stepper-content v-for="(item,index) in steps" :key="index" :step="index+1">
      <slot :name="item.slot"></slot>
    </v-stepper-content>
  </v-stepper-items>
```

Mobile snippet

```
<v-stepper-content :key="`${index}-stepContent-mobile`" :step="index+1">
    <slot :name="item.slot"></slot>
  </v-stepper-content>
```

**I tried doing a slot scope, but that doesn't seem to apply here**

```
<v-stepper-items>
    <v-stepper-content v-for="(item,index) in steps" :key="index" :step="index+1">
      <template :slot-scope="item.slot"><slot :name="item.slot"></slot></template>
    </v-stepper-content>
  </v-stepper-items>
```

**This is how the user would setup the slot when using the component** which can be seen [here](https://github.com/jasonwilczak/vuetify-simple-wizard/blob/master/dev/App.vue)

```
 <div slot="page5">
    <h4>Step 3</h4>
  </div>
```

So the key here is that the user sets up one slot when using the component, but the component puts that slot in 2 places in the .vue file, one in the desktop section and one in the mobile section.  It needs to have the same name, however, as it's effectively the same slot...

Here is my github project with the code, you can pull it down and run `npm install` and then `npm run dev` to see it in action: [Vuetify-Simple-Wizard](https://github.com/jasonwilczak/vuetify-simple-wizard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Portal-Vue](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/#/guide?id=switching-targets-and-sources) to multi-cast the step slots to the two locations (desk and mobile).

Since portal's target name can be dynamic, it works when resizing the window after initial render, i.e whenever `isMobile` changes value the portal re-evaluates and moves it's content to the appropriate section.

```html
<v-stepper v-model="stepStage" :alt-labels="!isMobile" :vertical="isMobile" >
  <div v-show="!isMobile">
    ...
    <v-stepper-items>
      <v-stepper-content v-for="(item,index) in steps" :key="index" :step="index+1">
        <portal-target :name="`portal-desk-${index}`" :key="index" slim></portal-target>
      </v-stepper-content>
    </v-stepper-items>
    ...
  </div>
  <div v-show="isMobile">
    <template v-for="(item,index) in steps">
      ...
      <v-stepper-content :key="`${index}-stepContent-mobile`" :step="index+1">
        <portal-target :name="`portal-mobile-${index}`" :key="index" slim></portal-target>
      </v-stepper-content>
      ...
    </template>
  </div>  

  <template v-for="(item, index) in steps">
    <portal :to="portalName(index)" :key="index">
      <template :slot-scope="item.slot"><slot :name="item.slot"></slot></template>
    </portal>
  </template>

</v-stepper>
```

```js
computed: {
  portalName() {
    return (index) => {
      const section = this.isMobile ? 'mobile' : 'desk';
      return `portal-${section}-${index}` 
    }
  }
},
```

---

### v-if

I'm not sure what problems you found with `v-if`, but it seems to work with v-if on `v-stepper-content`

```html
<div v-show="!isMobile">
  ...
  <v-stepper-content v-if="!isMobile" v-for="(item,index) in steps" :key="index" :step="index+1">
  ...
<div v-show="isMobile">
  ...
  <v-stepper-content v-if="isMobile" :key="`${index}-stepContent-mobile`" :step="index+1">
```

Comment: This looks really promising!  Thanks for this!  My issue with v-if is that the stepStage was not being read correctly by v-stepper and wasn't setting the first stage as active.  Even on forced renders, mounting, etc. it wouldn't set the stage as active until i pressed the next button.  I could hack around it by setting stage to 0 and triggering, but it felt wrong.

I just noticed that you did it on v-stepper-content, I was doing it higher due to the differences in structure between vertical and horizontal v-stepper.

Comment: Just gave it a try and I feel like this is the right answer.  Something is off though, it's not setting the slot into the portal target, it's just an empty element.  It's quite possible I'm not using it correctly, but I just pushed the changes to the simplewizard.vue file...

Comment: I've been working on it as well, the code as posted is not correct. The portal element needs a `<template v-for="(item, index) in steps">` wrapper and the portal names need to be unique. For this I used a computed property which returns strings in the format `portal-mobile-1`, `portal-desk-1` etc. Now the step content is in the correct place.

Comment: The last remaining problem is all `stepper-content` elements have `display: none` attribute which I'm sure is set by vuetify, but can't figure out why (normally the current `stepper-content` is not display: none, and it changes as you step). Will post revisions when that is solved.

Comment: The stepper-content display is usually set by the "step" property matching the v-model of the stepper, same goes for the header item...still working through

Comment: Based on what you said about `step` property matching `v-model` on stepper, I adjusted the portal content and moved the `step` property back into the main template. Now it works. I think the problem is that both portal and stepper are dynamic elements, and there is some contention about when the content is placed. Since `step` is key for stepper, it is best to keep it out of the portal content.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this was really what made it work and overall feels like a pretty good solution!!  I'll be looking forward to pushing this to npm, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You could break the component up into **SimpleWizardMobile** and **SimpleWizardDesk**, then use a dynamic component template in SimpleWizard,

**template**

```html
<template>
  <component :is="deviceType" 
    :completeStep="completeStep" 
    :previousStepLabel="previousStepLabel"
    :nextStepLabel="nextStepLabel"
    :steps="steps"
    :onNext="onNext"
    :onBack="onBack"
    :mobileBreakpoint="mobileBreakpoint"
    :theme="theme"
    ></component>
</template>
```

**component**

```js
<script>
import SimpleWizardDesk from './SimpleWizardDesk'
import SimpleWizardMobile from './SimpleWizardMobile'
...
computed: {
  deviceType() {
    return this.isMobile ? SimpleWizardMobile : SimpleWizardDesk
  }
},
```

I confirmed that your dev harness is still working with this structure, but have not worked out all the js refactoring (just used the same component for each and refactored the templates).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was afraid this might be my only option... My hang up was definitely around how to handle the JavaScript part especially since most of it is exactly the same... I'm going to do some more digging and then maybe give this route a try.